# Unable to import CngKey

Tags: c#, jwt, encode

I have this code:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "id", Id },
            { "username", Name },
            { "roles", string.Join(",", RolesIds) }
        };

        var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

        var cngKey = CngKey.Import(privateKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);

        var token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKeyBytes, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.ES256);
```

When I try to create cngKey from my private key (which is elliptic curve private key) it throws an exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The parameter is incorrect.'

How to solve it?